# RDS postgres restore wal2json replication slot without LSN disruption so ETL does not de-sync

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, etl

I have to perform a major upgrade on a RDS postgres instance, this instance has a wal2json replication slot that an ETL. According to the RDS docs this replication slot needs to be removed before a major upgrade. However removing the replication slot will cause a de-sync with the ETL which post upgrade and re-adding the replication slot, everything will need re-sync'd, this is not desirable.

Is there a way to restore the replication slot post upgrade so the replcation slot can be restored and no dy-sync occurs? perhaps inserting the prior LSN number into the pg_replication slot row, but then how do I tell the instance to keep the WAL files around so that position still exists?